# how to add multiple roles to user_role in one cell (LARAVEL 8x)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hi im bad at explaining so bare with me please :)

I got `roles` `users` and `user_role`. i currently have a ***multi-select-box*** to assign a user a role, but the `user_role` only saves one role_id from the select-boxes .

**My questions:**

- How can i save multiple `role_id` in one cell in `user_role`?
- How do i check if user has a duplicate role in the database?

--

My UserRoleController#Store

```
public function store(UserRoleStoreRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $roles_ar = $validated['role_id'];
    $roles="";
    foreach($roles_ar as $key => $role){
        if (isset($role)){
        $roles.= $key . $role . ',';
        };}
        // dd($roles);
    $user = User::find($validated['user_id']);
    $user->roles()->attach([$roles]);
    return redirect('/user-role');
}
```

connect.blade.php (Multi-select-input-box)

```
 <select class="form-control" name="user_id">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        @if($users)
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{ $user['id'] }}" ><h3>{{ $user['name'] }}</h3></option>
        @endforeach
        @endif
</select>

<label class="description">Role</label>
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Use CTRL to multiselect</label>
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" name="role_id[]">
    @if($roles)
    @foreach($roles as $role)
    <option value="{{ $role['id'] }}" ><h3>{{ $role['name'] }}</h3></option>
    @endforeach
    @endif
</select>
```

Comment: attach accepts an array of ids so you can ->attach($roles_ar);

Comment: you can call $user->roles()->detach(); to remove all roles first.

Comment: I don't know what u mean with ur first command. could u explain a little more please? im not that technical with words.

Comment: okay, I explained it in the answer section.

Comment: go with a **pivot table concept**

Comment: Hi chris i have same issue i have successfully saved the data put i want to apply same process as in your code can you help me with your solution or code i am getting null array from my module_id[] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71814696/create-new-user-and-make-relationship-in-one-go?noredirect=1#comment126908263_71814696    in my case i have a script which add more select element if user click on add more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach multiple roles to a user, you can call `attach` method and provide an array of IDs as an argument. Since you already have an array of IDs from the input in variable `$roles_ar`, then you can call attach like so.

```
$user->roles()->attach($roles_ar);
```

You also asked how to check for duplicates of roles in the database. But you don't have to check for duplicates if you remove all the existing roles in the database then attach all the new ones. So you should call `detach` method first before calling `attach` method above.

```
$user->roles()->detach();
```

Thanks to @brombeer you can use `sync()` instead of calling `detach()` then `attach()`

```
$user->roles()->sync($roles_ar);
```

Comment: Might want to use [->sync()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) instead of detach/attach